# How to display a query record count in a form control

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I have a query that returns a fluid # of records, depending on criteria selected in the form.  I would like to display the total # of records returned to the form.

I have added a **unbound text field** to the footer in the form that is displaying the controls and resulting records. I tried the following expressions in the text field, both of which result in **#error**:

```
=Count([qrnname]![fieldtocount])
=DCount([qrnname]![fieldtocount])
```

This should be simple.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`DCount` requires string values for its arguments.  Assuming `fieldtocount` is the name of a field returned by the named query `qrnname`, use this as your text box's Control Source ...

```vb
=DCount("[fieldtocount]", "qrnname")
```

Since that query depends on criteria selected in the form, `Requery` the text box whenever those criteria change to update the count displayed in the text box.

Answer (score 2):

use this `=DCount([fieldtocount]![qrnname])`

The syntax for the **DCount** function is:

`DCount ( expression, domain, [criteria] )`

expression is the field that you use to count the number of records.

domain is the set of records. This can be a table or a query name.

criteria is optional. It is the WHERE clause to apply to the domain.

[Dcount in detail](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/domain/dcount.php)

Answer (score 1):

An other alternative is to use `=Count(primaryKey)` in the Control Source property

[image: Text Box Property]

It seems better if you have some filter on your original query, so you don't have to apply them again in the `DCount (expression, domain, [criteria])` function.

[A quick method for counting Access records in a form](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/microsoft-office/a-quick-method-for-counting-access-records-in-a-form/)

Comment: When the filter returns 0 records, this solution does not display 0