# Access - Display Count of Records in Textbox

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access

I have an Access Application.  It opens on a search form and the user selects the criteria, hits "Search" and it displays list of records that meets their criteria.  The user then clicks on a record, and it displays the information about that record.  All of this works great, but I am trying to add a "Count" feature, that will display a textbox showing the number of times that user is in the database.

But my textbox only ever displays "1".

In my textbox:  I have the following:

```
=Count([Requester_UserName])
```

Because a Requester can have many entries in the database, I want to show a count of how many entries they have on this form, although the form only displays information about the one specific record, so this specific user might have 15 entries.  How do I get this form to show "15" in that textbox?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I literally Googled "Access - Display Count of Records in Textbox" and got a zillion duplicate questions ;)

Comment: E.g. [How to display a query record count in a form control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19278612/how-to-display-a-query-record-count-in-a-form-control)

Comment: Absinthe:  So did I, but none of the sites I found worked.  I tried them all and it still displays "1".  I never understand why people have to be rude

Comment: I meant no offense, please don't take it that way. You're asking a really simple question for which there are many answers available already. On Stack we try to avoid duplicate questions. Maybe best if you read some VBA tutorials to get more familiar with the language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't count (no pun intended) on the `.Count` method. It's unreliable for various scenarios. Use a SQL statement instead. Here's a multipurpose method:

```
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'Purpose  : Retrieve number of records
'
'Prereq.  : ADO 2.x
'Parameter: cn       - Initialized ADODB.Connection object
'           sTable   - Table name
'           sField   - DB column name used for COUNT. This is ideally a integer column
'           sFilter  - SQL WHERE clause
'Returns  : # of records
'Note     : -
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Public Function SQLCount(ByVal cn As ADODB.Connection, ByVal sTable As String, Optional ByVal sField As String = "*", _
   Optional ByVal sFilter As String = vbNullString) As Long
   Dim rs As ADODB.RecordSet
   Dim lRecCount As Long
   Dim sSQL As String
   
   sSQL = "SELECT COUNT([" & sField & _
      "]) AS RecCount FROM [" & sTable & "]"
               
   If Len(sFilter) Then
      sSQL = sSQL & " WHERE " & sFilter
   End If
   sSQL = sSQL & ";"
               
   Set rs = New ADODB.RecordSet
   
   rs.Open sSQL, cn
   
   If Not (rs.BOF And rs.EOF) Then
      lRecCount = rs.Fields("RecCount").Value
   End If
   
   rs.Close
   Set rs = Nothing

   SQLCount = lRecCount
   
End Function
'==============================================================================
```

Assuming the ADODB table name is MyTable, ID is a integer column in that table and you want to know how many records with 'Miami' are stored in the field named City, you call it like

`Debug.Print SQLCount(cn, "MyTable", "ID", "City = 'Miami")`

Comment: Thank you.  That is what I needed to do.  I couldn't get it to do it on the form itself, but needed to do it in code in the backend.  Thank you for pointing this out, appreciate it.